# Союзы типа «кроме того(,) что», «помимо того(,) что», «по мере того(,) что», «по мере того(,) как»

Tags: пунктуация, союзы

Скажите, пожалуйста, к какому типу придаточных относятся союзы типа "кроме того(,) что", "помимо того(,) что",  "по мере того(,) что", "по мере того(,) как"? И если внутри подобных союзов ставится запятая, то его первая часть выступает как соотносительное слово, то есть выполняет роль дополнения (например: предлог "кроме" + указательное местоимение "того") и помогает определить тип придаточного?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Скажите, пожалуйста, к какому типу придаточных относятся союзы типа "кроме того(,)
 что", "помимо того(,) что", "по мере того(,) что", "по мере того(,) как"?
```

Вы хотели спросить, в придаточных предложениях какого типа могут быть средством связи названные союзы?

Тип придаточного предложения следует определять по тому, на какой вопрос оно отвечает, а не по союзу или союзному слову, которым оно присоединено. Составные союзы включают в себя указательные слова, которые показывают, что при главной части имеется придаточная. Это указательные местоимения и местоимённые наречия то, тот, такой, там, туда, тогда, столько и другие, которые выступают в паре с определёнными союзами и союзными словами: то — что, там — где, столько — сколько и т. д. При определённых типах придаточных наличие указательного слова обязательно, в этом случае придаточное относится именно к нему.

```
    И если внутри подобных союзов ставится запятая, то его первая часть выступает 
    как соотносительное слово, то есть выполняет роль дополнения (например:
    предлог "кроме" + указательное местоимение "того") и помогает определить тип придаточного?
```

Хоть ставится запятая, хоть не ставится, союз действительно **помогает** определить тип придаточного, потому что помогает поставить вопрос к нему, а по вопросу определяется тип. Есть составные союзы, в которых всегда ставится запятая, к ним как раз относятся **за исключением того, что; кроме того, что; помимо того, что** - это предложные обороты со значением включения. Предлоги требуют дополнения в родительном падеже, значит, вопрос тоже будет соответствующий - помимо чего? кроме чего? Придаточное изъяснительное.

По мере того(,) что", "по мере того(,) как" независимо от постановки запятой потребуют вопроса когда?, а не чего? какого того?

По мере того как я продвигался в лес, страх охватывал меня всё больше. - Страх охватывал когда? - придаточное времени.

Страх пропадал по мере того, как я наблюдал приметы приближения к дому. Страх пропадал когда? - придаточное времени. С чем его можно перепутать? С местоимённо-определительным?

Но местоименно-определительные придаточные раскрывают **признак предмета**  и присоединяются к главному предложению с помощью союзных слов (основные союзные слова - кто и что = который). У нас не признак предмета и КАК нельзя заменить на КОТОРЫЙ.

С придаточным изъяснительным?  Но придаточные  изъяснительные зависят от существительного  как от слова с определённым значением (речи, мысли, чувства, восприятия),  к ним можно задать и падежный вопрос, они раскрывают (изъясняют) **содержание речи, мысли, чувства,** восприятия и присоединяются к главному союзами и союзными словами. Тоже не подходит.

Так что вопрос - главное средство распознавания типа придаточного предложения.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! А если союз разделяется, значит, один его элемент остаётся в главной части и выступает как второстепенных член, а другой уходит в придаточную?

Comment: Именно так, Вы правы